# How can I change color of writer.println

Tags: java, file, text, colors

I want to write some text into the text file using following code in Java:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\TEXT_FILE.txt", "UTF-8");     
    writer.println("some text");
```

The question is how is possible to change color of "some text" into the file.

Comment: A txt file has only text, no color.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in a text file. You must use odf, rtf, doc (xdoc) or html. Each files has their own standard about how to add color to a text.